# CGI, python, and setgid

Tags: python, cgi

I'm running a compiled python cgi script (using cxfreeze) in Apache.
The script, among other things, calls

```
os.setuid(some_uid)
os.setgid(some_gid)
```

Obviously some_uid/gid are legal and I set the sticky bit for both user and group, and verified it is indeed set.
However on every call i get an error

```
os.setgid(int(self.gid))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

As you may notice, `setuid()` is successful, `setgid()` is not. Which is very weird, at least for me, though I admit I have little experience with permissions in Linux.
Any thoughts/ideas are welcome.

I'm using apache 2.2.15, python 2.6.5, RHEL 5.4 (kernel 2.6.18)

Answer (score 3):

The setuid call drops the privileges you need to call setgid, so your calls occur in the wrong order. But why not use a [library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/privilege/1.0) that is designed for dropping privileges?

Comment: Of course. stupid of me. 
Thank you very much and I will look into the library you suggested